# Build errors after updating from VS2003 to VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a project that works well and without error in VS2003, but I have to update it to 2010 for some reason. After updating the project, when building the project, I get these errors:

```
1.errorLNK1179:Invalid or corrupt files ：duplicate comdat“IIDIDispatchEx”
2.IIDIDispatchEx duplicate initialization on file dispeX.h(121)
```

What I found about LNK1179 says the error might be caused by I having more than one COMDAT share the same name, and using `/h` to limit the length of the external Name, while packaging the /Gy in COMDAT.
But there isn't a `/H` option used in code, and I have disabled `/Gy`. but the error still occurred.

Searching `dispeX.h`, I found it in `MicrosoftSDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\`. The code in line 121 is:

```
DEFINEGUID(IIDIDispatchEx, 0xa6ef9860, 0xc720, 0x11d0, 0x93, 0x37, 0x0, 0xa0, 0xc9, 0xd, 0xca, 0xa9);
```

I don't know how to solve this, any help or explanation or guide into the right direction will be very welcome.

Comment: It was hard to make sense of this, so I have tried to beat some grammar into it. Please carefully re-read your question and check whether I have changed the meaning of something by doing so. Unfortunately, I can't really help you with the issue itself.

Comment: The linker output should mention some `.obj` and `.lib` files. Does it? I would expect the error occur if there was a mismatch between compiler options used for compiling those objects rather than just because some options were used.